# No route matches - after login attempt - even though the route exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am working on a rails application and added a simple login system according to a book.

I created the controller admin: 
rails generate controller admin login logout index

It added the following routes to routes.db

```
  get "admin/login"
  get "admin/logout"
  get "admin/index"
```

1. I can got to http://localhost:3000/admin/login there is no problem at all.
2. But when I try to login I get: No route matches "/admin/login"!

Now, the first confusing part is that the "login" method of my AdminController is not executed at all.

The second confusing part is that this code works like a charm - redirects everything to /admin/login:

```
  def authorize
    unless User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) 
      flash[:notice] = "you need to login" 
      redirect_to :controller => 'admin', :action => 'login'
    end
  end
```

Sidenotes:

- I restarted the server several times.
- I tried a different browser - to be sure there is no caching problem.

Comment: I think that when you are trying to login this is POST request, not GET. Show your login form code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
match "/admin/login" => "admin#login"
match "/admin/logout" => "admin#logout"
match "/admin/index" => "admin#index"
```

(notice the leading /)

As an aside, unless you're creating a login system to learn about Rails and/or authentication, you're probably better off using something like Devise.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the leading slash doesn't matter in Rails routes. The advice to use Devise is spot on, though.

Comment: It seems you're right about the optional leading slash. But replacing `get` with `match` should correct the case where credentials are POSTed

Answer (score 1):

Following on from David Sulc's answer:

You're defining the routes as `get` requests, meaning to go to them you must perform a `GET /admin/login` request which is basically what happens when you type the URL into your address bar or follow a link that uses it.

However when you try to use these URLs in a form, the form does a `POST` request and because you've defined all of these as `get`-only requests, Rails will not be able to find a compatible route.

I definitely agree with David that you should look at an alternative system such as Devise.